# Orientation changes when pop back to the initial viewcontroller using UINavigationController iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a presented a navigation controller, in which the root view controller i,e. VC1 is supported for both landscape & portrait orientations. When i push another view controller in landscape the i,e. VC2 which supports only portrait mode, come back to the VC1, the view will be turned to portrait. But i am still in the landscape mode. Please help me to solve this on iOS 6 issue.

Please check the below code.

```
MyViewController1 *theController =[[MyViewController1 alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navCntlr = [[UINavigationController alloc]      initWithRootViewController:theController];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navCntlr animated:YES completion:nil];           [theController release];
[navCntlr release];
```

in MyViewController1

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

in VC2/MyViewController2 i have added the below code.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

i have subclassed the root navigation bar as well.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this was identified as a bug in IOS6 happens with ImageViewController which only supports Portrait orientation ... so i spent lot of time and found a way around the same....

hope this helps
so first things first...

add a property in your AppDelegate.h

```
@property BOOL model;
```

then
in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.model=NO;

    return YES;
}
```

also add this method in AppDelegate.m

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{

    if(!self.model)
        return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape; //or needed orientation
    else

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;


}
```

then in your view controller before presenting the VC2

implement
this code...

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            appdelegate.model=YES;
```

and then you just change the value in the viewWillDisappear of VC2

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            appdelegate.model=NO;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Raon..                                     I think i have not explained my problem clearly, Sorry for that. VC1 should support both the orientation whr VC2 should support only the portrait, when i go to VC2 in landscape it shld display its view in portrait only, after selecting back from VC2 the in landscape mode. VC1 view shld be in landscape but its not happening currently. As VC2 is not supported for the landscape when i go & come VC1 view also get rotated to portrait. Plz suggest

Comment: @user2960314 so you're saying you need the same orientation ie,
VC1 may be in landscape/portrait >> VC2(portrait) >> VC1 (landscape or portrait)

so if
VC1 was portrait before it should return to portrait when it reappears after VC2
similarly
if Vc2 was landscape it should remain Landscape..

Comment: @Raon..  Its very abnormal way of testing. i found this issue when i keep device in landscape from VC1 and push another view VC2 which supports only portrait, hence it loads its view in portrait only (Note that the device is still in landscape) , select back on the VC2 now the VC1 which supports both the orientation has changed its view to portrait, even though the device is still in landscape. The problem is in VC1 which shld be in landscape when i come back also but its not.

Comment: @user2960314  is this a problem with 6.0 ?or any other has the same problem?

Comment: Not sure @Raon So only i posted here. so that if any other have the same problem.